# Como adicionar o "android-support-v13.jar" em meu projeto?

Tags: android

Estou acompanhando o livro "Android Application Development for Dummies" e chegou em uma parte do livro em que diz o seguinte: Copie o arquivo android-support-v13.jar para a pasta libs do seu projeto.

Fiz exatamente isso. Encontrei o arquivo na pasta do SDK. Copiei para o diretório libs onde está o meu projeto, e realizei uma limpeza no mesmo(clean), pelo eclipse. Porém, não está detectando o "android-support-v13.jar" na pasta "Android Dependences", como diz o livro.

Esta é realmente a maneira correta de "importar" o support v13 pro meu projeto no eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que fazer a referência à biblioteca importada no `project.properties`.

Em um HelloWorld, ele seria assim:

```
target=android-21
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
```

Nesse seu caso, deixaria ela desse modo:

```
target=<sua versão>
<bibliotecas já importadas>
android.library.reference.n+1=../android-support-v13
```

Comment: Eu fiz o que tu disseste, mas mesmo assim o Eclipse não reconheceu a biblioteca v13.
Ficou assim no meu project.properties: ======

target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7 //
android.library.reference.n+1=../android-support-v13 =====

Seria desta forma? 
Eu também já realizei a limpeza(clean), após o procedimento e nada.

Comment: O `n+1` é uma expressão matemática, não era pra ser digitado exatamente `n+1`, mas sim o próximo numero nas referências. Se o seu projeto tem 4 referências, então a linha correta seria `android.library.reference.5=../android-support-v13`

Answer (score 2):

Bom, imaginando que você esteja o Android Studio: Vá em File, depois clique em Project Structure. Dentro de Modules, vá em app e depois dependencies. No canto superior direito há um botão com sinal (+), clique nele e depois em 'File Dependency'. Pronto, agorá só adicionar a lib "android-support-v13.jar".

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas estou utilizando o Eclipse. Você tem sugestões de como eu posso resolver esse problema por lá?

Comment: Desculpa @sTokes, não tenho ideia, faz muito tempo que não uso Eclipse. Att